# mysql group by having return a set

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I know there are many similar threads out there pertaining to this but I can't find one that fits my situation.

What I'm looking for is a mysql statement that will allow me to group by user_id and return the max id set (id is NOT a unique column).

Here is my data:

```
id      url_id  submit_date         engine  status  message
14738   3629    2009-01-02 18:43:55 0pn 10  NULL
14738   3629    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Abacho  10  NULL
14738   3629    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Acoon   10  NULL
14739   3629    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Alexa   10  NULL
14739   3629    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Amfibi  10  NULL
14739   3629    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Burf    10  NULL
14740   4115    2009-01-02 18:43:55 0pn 10  NULL
14740   4115    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Abacho  10  NULL
14740   4115    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Acoon   10  NULL
14741   4115    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Alexa   10  NULL
14741   4115    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Amfibi  10  NULL
14741   4115    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Burf    10  NULL
```

Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE url_id IN (3629,4115) group by url_id having max(id);
```

The problem is that the statement only outputs only the top search engine for that set. I need all the search engines included in that ID set. I also do not want to use nested sql statements since it causes quite a significant performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table A,
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE url_id IN (3629,4115) group by url_id having max(id)) B
WHERE A.id=B.id;
```

Comment: I know I mentioned I didn't want nested statements, but this query did the trick. It returned my results in 1.3 seconds in a database with 377K results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you would like to avoid the use of subqueries and derived tables, you should try using a self-exclusion join.
Explanation: with the self-join, we create another table with which to compare the first table to find the most-recent `id`, i.e. the row(s) with no greater `id` value for each `url_id`.

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM yourtable t 
       LEFT JOIN yourtable t2 
       ON t2.url_id = t.url_id
   AND t2.id > t.id
 WHERE t.url_id IN (3629,4115)
   AND t2.id IS NULL;
```

Which returns this (I omitted the last two columns while testing b/c they don't matter in this example):

```
14739   3629    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Alexa
14739   3629    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Amfibi
14739   3629    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Burf
14741   4115    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Alexa
14741   4115    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Amfibi
14741   4115    2009-01-02 18:43:55 Burf
```

[SQLized here](http://sqlize.com/7Fs0tKZCgA).  (Self-joins don't appear to be supported so same table is defined and populated twice.)